# What are some limitations of survey raking weights?

Tags: survey, weights, survey-weights

The title of this question says it all. I know that all methods have limitations, and while I know some of the strengths of raking weights (e.g., often, only marginal distributions for auxiliary variables are necessary), I'm not sure where raking weights wouldn't be appropriate or what their limitations might be.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Rim aka raking weighting assumes that the "forces" which distorted the structure in the sample (relative the true, population structure), operated on the variables independently, aka marginally. The distortion between genders (say) occured independently from the distortion between age groups. And that is logically why we "cure" the distortion by the proportional fitting algo which operates on marginals.